# C Segmentation Fault (core dumped) while concatenating strings

Tags: c, string, pointers, concatenation

I'm trying to write a program in C that takes in three pointers to characters, two of which are strings that are input by a user, and the last string is the final string the user wants to write a concatenated string to. I don't know much about memory management, but was told I have to use malloc * 250 to get the size of each string. I was also told I have to use pointers in order to solve this problem.

Anyways, after inputting both strings via scanf, I get a Segmentation Fault (core dumped) error with no other explanation. I'm guessing it has something to do with the way I'm referencing the pointers in my str_concat function, but I don't know where to start.

Here is my code including the str_concat function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void str_concat(char* str1, char* str2, char* str);

int main() {
        char* str1;
        char* str2;
        char* finalString;
        str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);
        str2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);
        finalString = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);
        // input
        printf("Enter string 1: ");
        scanf("%s", str1);
        printf("Enter string 2: ");
        scanf("%s", str2);
        // concatenate
        str_concat(str1, str2, finalString);
        printf("Final string: %s\n", finalString);
        free(str1);
        free(str2);
        free(finalString);

        return 0;
}

void str_concat(char* str1, char* str2, char* str) {
        // go through string 1 up until terminating character
        while(*str1 != '\0') {
                *str = *str1; // copy str1 to final string up until the terminating character
                str++; // increment position of final string
        } // end while
        while(*str2 != '\0') {
                *str = *str2; // copy string 2 starting at final position of string 1
                str++; // increment position of final string
                str2++; // increment string 2 so we can go through values
        } // end while
        *str = '\0'; // add a null terminating character to the string to finish
}
```

Comment: `str1++` is missing in the first `while`.

Comment: You never increment `str1` in your first loop copy. eventually you blast off the end of your target string writing the same char over and over. `while (*str1) *str++ = *str1++;`

Comment: @Alex Curious: in `str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);`, what/who suggested coding `sizeof(char)` which is always 1?

Comment: @chux In our lab for assembly / C programming, the professor said thats how we have to allocate memory for a string :|

Comment: @Alex Wonder what the prof would think of `str1 = malloc(250 * sizeof *str1)`?  If prof does not like that, "just smile and nod" and know someday you will graduate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function is wrong. You forgot to increase pointer `str1` in loop

```
    while(*str1 != '\0') {
            *str = *str1; // copy str1 to final string up until the terminating character
            str++; // increment position of final string
    } // end while
```

The function can be written simpler

```
char * str_concat( const char *str1, const char *str2, char *str ) 
{
    char *p = str;

    while ( *p = *str1++ ) ++p;
    while ( *p = *str2++ ) ++p;

    return str; 
}
```

Take into account that string functions usually follow the common convention according to which they return a pointer to a string.

Answer (score -1):

Your *finalString* should be the sum of lengths of str1 and str2 plus one.

```
str1 = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);
str2 = malloc(sizeof(char)*250);
finalString = malloc(sizeof(char)*501);
```

Comment: Strictly speaking, it should be minus one, because both strings have a null-terminator, but you only need one null terminator on the output string.